# Server Control Auto Postback with form has _blank attribute

Tags: asp.net, forms, autopostback

My case is I have an asp.net page has a form

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" target="_blank">
```

and a button redirect to another page and this page will open in a new window because of the target attribute of the form .

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/kindofpage.aspx" Text="Generate" />
```

and I have a dropdownlist has auto postback = true to post the past to fill another dropdownlist by selected data .

```
<asp:dropdownliast id="Make" name="Make" runat="server" autopostback="true"></asp:dropdownlist>
```

the question is : why when I select item from the auto postbacked dropdown an blank page opened ?

I need a way to post the page by the dropdownlist without openning a blank page ..

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

For lack of a better idea, you could just remove the `target="_blank"` attribute from your markup, and when your button is clicked, modify the `form` tag with JavaScript and set the attribute.

You can set the [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) property and run JavaScript when it's clicked. For example:

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" OnClientClick="document.getElementById('form1').setAttribute('target', '_blank')" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/kindofpage.aspx" Text="Generate" />
```

Comment: page will not get redirected in new tab until `button1` is not clicked. but, what happen once the `target=_blank` attribute is set. Whenever we click on any link it will redirect the page on new tab instead of same window. Is there any way that sets the `target` attribute temporarily until page is not redirected then it should get set to `_self` or removed from the form tag?

Answer (score 0):

You could always just adjust your buttonpress code to open a new window such as this:

```
<asp:Button ID="myBtn" runat="server" Text="Click me" 
 onclick="myBtn_Click" OnClientClick="window.open('kindofpage.aspx', 'kindofpage');" />
```

then remove the:

```
target="_blank"
```

From the form tag.

Comment: removing target from the form tag inside child page ?

Comment: Use the code I posted in conjunction with making your form tag : <form id="form1" runat="server"> . The javascipt command window.open, will take care of opening a new tab on the button press only and not when you postback via the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a similar situation but solved it in the following way. 
As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8138529/4386387), you can use the OnClientClick property to set the target to "_blank". E.g.

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" OnClick="codebehind_method" OnClientClick="document.forms[0].target = '_blank';" runat="server" Text="targets new window" />
```

Then, in the aspx page that my "codebehind_method" function redirects to, I reset the target of the opener form like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function resetTarget() { 
opener.document.forms[0].target = ''; 
}
</script>
<body onload="resetTarget()">
```

Now, if you go back to your opener form and use a control that does not have the "OnClientClick" property set, the AutoPostBack should occur in the same tab. 
If you want to find your form by ID, replace "document.forms[0]" with:

```
document.getElementByID('yourFormName')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```